# How to expand a column based on values ( Years)

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I have a data like that :

```
structure(list(Event = c(2015L, 2017L, 2015L, 2018L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

I want to make each year (value) separate and then make those columns binominal like this.

```
structure(list(X2015 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    X2016 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X2017 = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X2018 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

So it means making columns for each year.

Comment: You can use `model.matrix(~ factor(Event) -1, df1)` or `library(dummies);dummy(df1$Event)`

Comment: If you want a tidyverse approach, you might try `df %>% mutate(ID = 1:n(), dummy = 1) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Event, values_from = dummy, values_fill = 0, names_glue = "X{Event}") %>% select(-ID)`.